# Trying to update attributefields from shapefile with field values from intersecting shapefile features

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, intersection

I have two shapefiles. This code selects features from shp1, which intersect with features from shp2.
I need to update two fields from shp2 with the values of the intersecting features form shp1.

Selection code:

```
#add layer
zamg_new = iface.addVectorLayer('shp1.shp',"", "ogr")
newlayer = iface.addVectorLayer('shp2.shp',"", "ogr")
#zamg_new.setCrs(crsSrc)
#newlayer.setCrs(crsSrc)

#select intersect
zamg_zone = []
for rel_feature in newlayer.getFeatures():
    for zone_feature in zamg_new.getFeatures():
        if rel_feature.geometry().intersects(zone_feature.geometry()):
            zamg_zone.append(zone_feature.id())

zamg_new.select(zamg_zone)
#print(zamg_zone)
```

Selected feat from shp1

[image: selected feat from shp1:]

table of shp2, with the fields which need to be updated with the values of the selected features from shp1.

[image: table of shp2, with field which need to be updated with selected features]

For example REL_1, REL_3, REL_4 intersect with Zamg_are 1 and get values from this feature and REL_4 is in Zamg_are 2 and gets those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this by using a spatial index for a greater performance. Check the code comments for explanations. As mentioned in the last comment, you did not mention what should happen if there is more than one intersection feature, so I just added a `break` to skip the iteration after the first intersection-match. You may need to find some logic for this, if there can be more matches.

```py
#add layer
#iface.addVectorLayer('shp1.shp',"", "ogr")
#iface.addVectorLayer('shp2.shp',"", "ogr")

#get layers
zamg_new = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('shp1')[0]
newlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('shp2')[0]

#create a spatial index
zamg_new_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(zamg_new.getFeatures())

#do the job
with edit(newlayer): # dont forget to turn on edit mode, otherwise you cannot write attribute values to it
    for rel_feature in newlayer.getFeatures(): # iterate over the newlayer
        for zone_feature_id in zamg_new_idx.intersects(rel_feature.geometry().boundingBox()): # check if the features bounding boxes intersect by using the spatial index
            zone_feature = zamg_new.getFeature(zone_feature_id) # get the feature by its id
            if rel_feature.geometry().intersects(zone_feature.geometry()): # check if the features really intersect
                rel_feature['H_gradient'] = zone_feature['gradient'] # assign attribute, change fieldnames if necessary
                rel_feature['b3_T150'] = zone_feature['b3T150'] # assign attribute, change fieldnames if necessary
                newlayer.updateFeature(rel_feature) # dont foreget to update the feature you just gave new values to
                break # only do it for the first intersecting feature... you may need another logic if there are more matches
```

Comment: Thank you!! this works fine. I Think in my case the break solution for multiple intersection is enough. Otherwise I would have to make the decision dependent on the size of the overlapping area -> chose values from larger intersection area. I guess that's the only logic that could work